# Display vertical image in the left side of jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

[image]

I want to display an image (with help of *iReport*) like in the attached file. I want to display it in the first page also. How can i design this?

Comment: use background section in ireport, and in all other bands.. used left margin to not to overlap your other details on the image attached

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use Background section in IReport to add your image.
and in all other sections use left margin for all elements so that image will not overlap with other elements.

use this sample code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="bgreport" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="0.9090909090909102"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="637"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select 1 from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="?column?" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <background>
        <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="Clip">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="113" height="802"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["/home/manideep/manideep/temp/cherry.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="112" y="0" width="100" height="79"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Title]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="112" y="0" width="100" height="35"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Page Header]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="112" y="0" width="100" height="61"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Column Header]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="112" y="0" width="100" height="125"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Detail Band]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="112" y="0" width="100" height="45"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Column Footer]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="112" y="0" width="100" height="54"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Page Footer]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="303" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="112" y="0" width="100" height="303"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Summary]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: `/home/manideep/manideep/temp/cherry.jpg` change this specific image you require.

Comment: This works also with textfields, if you need a vertical header on  the page side